# Chrome extension to listen to button click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can a Chrome extension listen to events within a web page, such as a button click or the user clicking on a menu? This is for an intranet app so security is not as critical here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083597/chrome-extension-event-listener-for-appended-code

Comment: See [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension - Event Listener for Appended Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083597/chrome-extension-event-listener-for-appended-code)